# What is the reason of "No module found error" for pyshark module?

Tags: python, pyshark

I wanted to take some suggestion and learn the reason of getting "No module found error" for pyshark module. I installed it however I'm still getting error. You can see short record below.

https://asciinema.org/a/MHAX4PeIg5yWSm40KcYqWQBDi

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the video you are using `pip3` to install but `python2.7` to execute the script. Use `pip2.7 install pyshark` to use it properly.

Comment: It did not work as well. You can see the result of your suggestion, which is same error.